# Hide remote branches with Git and SourceTree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

The origin has about a hundred branches that I don't care about and are probably not used.  In SourceTree, I have to look at all of them and select the main branch whenever I push.  Is there anyway I can hide all these branches?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just delete their tracking branches?

Comment: Because I didn't put them there.

Comment: I don't mean deleting them from your remote. I just mean deleting the local tracking branches, so they're no longer part of your local repository.

Comment: @Chris I tried it using 'git branch -D', but SourceTree still lists the branch.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's an option in git now to just clone a single branch.

```
git clone --single-branch <repo url>
```